# Discord js cannot find the channel to send error messages in

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have the following code writing text depending on what message was sent to it:

```
var text = null;
try {
 commandFiles.forEach((file) => {
  if (text != null) {
   return;
  }
  text = file.functionSwitch(event, command, commandArgs);
 });
} catch(err) {
 text = "I seem to have hit a problem. Please let bot creator look at it.";
 const errChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === errChannelID);
 errChannel.send(err.message);
}
```

The code gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

I am not sure how to fix this error or properly find the channel. I have attempted with both `get` and `find`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [fetch the channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) by its ID. `fetch()` returns a promise, and once it's resolved you'll receive the channel (I named it `ch` below) that has the ID `errChannelID`. So, if the channel with that ID exists, you can use its `send()` method to send the message, if it doesn't exist the promise is rejected and the function inside the `catch()` method runs:

```js
client.channels
  .fetch(errChannelID)
  .then((ch) => ch.send(err.message))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Make sure that `errChannelID` is a valid snowflake and is a string. If you store it as an integer and it's larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (2^53) it will not be representable in the number type and will be converted to something else by JavaScript.

Comment: Also, I have just tried that code. Now it gives me a DiscordAPIError saying "Unknown Channel". It's a new error, at least

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some details on how it works. It seems the ID is not a valid channel ID.

Comment: I am now looking at the error message it gives. For some reason, it gives "path: '/channels/827207044817879000'", when the channel id is 827207044817879091. Putting the id directly in the fetch did not help.

Comment: It seems you passed an integer as snowflake instead of a string. Integers above 2^53 are not representable in the number type. 827207044817879091 is larger than 2^53, so it will be converted to 827207044817879000 by JavaScript. Try to use quotes around it like: `const errChannelID = '827207044817879091'`.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much. I did not realise the integer limit could mess it up, though I should have figured with the 0's.